# PHPCS - Sniffs to enforce new lines after closures and before returns?

Tags: php, code-standards, phpcs

We're running various sniffs to help consistency, along with using eslint - so we're trying to unify some rules. we can do this in eslint but cant figure out how to do it in phpcs.

## New line after closures e.g

```
tap(function () {
    return true;
});

$cake = 'yes please';
```

to prevent

```
tap(function () {
    return true;
});
$cake = 'yes please';
```

## Force blank line before return statements (that are not the only statements in the method)

```
getSomething()
{
    $something = 'something';

    return $something;
}
```

or

```
getSomething()
{
    return 'something';
}
```

rather than

```
getSomething()
{
    $something = 'something';
    return $something;
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For empty lines before `return`, you can use `blank_line_before_statement` rule from [PHP CS Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer)

**To use it with PHP_CodeSniffer, the best way is to use [EasyCodingStandard](https://github.com/Symplify/EasyCodingStandard).**

#### 1. Install it

```
composer require --dev symplify\easy-coding-standard
```

#### 2. Configure it

```
# easy-coding-standard.neon
checkers:
    - PhpCsFixer\Fixer\ReturnNotation\BlankLineBeforeReturnFixer
```

#### 3. Run it on your code

```
vendor/bin/ecs check src
```

#### 4. Fix your code

```
vendor/bin/ecs check src --fix
```

*For closures you'd have to tune original rule to include closure token as well.*

If any troubles come up, just [create an issue here](https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/issues). I'm happy to improve this tool as much as possible.